# Убрать ActionBar (Toolbar?)

Tags: android, actionbar, android-toolbar, android-style

Здравствуйте.

Появилась небольшая проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пустое пространство под ActionBar - на Android 4 оно не отображается, только на 5+.

Фрагмент из манифеста:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.evgeny.manko.egeshka.testsys.TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_test_system"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"></style>

<style name="ToolBarWithNavigationBack"></style>

<style name="AppTheme.Russian">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/lightBlue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/lightBlueDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

В лаяуте про actionbar ничего нет

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Поставьте в манифест тему android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" или перенесите те две строчки из `NoActionBar` в `AppTheme`

Answer (score 0):

в activity_main во фрагменте поставить app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"